# How to load dynamic data from remote server

Tags: javascript, apache, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have html page running in apache server,
eg: Lets consider I have one index.html that is present in the sample folder. index.html file have some API calls that need to point to remote server, I mean actual data needs to come from server.

Local app is running in : `localhost/sample`

I need to get the info from : `https://stackoverflow.com/sample/project`

How to config the Apache server?

I did the same approach in nodejs http-server and set the proxy config as
`http-server --proxy https://stackoverflow.com/` its working as expected, but I'm not sure how to configure in Apache

Thanks